# Validity of “I saw someone scream”

Tags: meaning

I don’t understand “I saw someone scream.” Is it right to say “I heard someone scream” or “I saw someone who was screaming”?

Comment: I don’t understand either. Why are you interested in knowing whether what you ***saw*** was "someone scream" or "someone who was screaming"? Syntactically speaking, both are perfectly valid, and mean exactly the same, but it's far more natural to say *I **heard** someone scream / who was screaming*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid.  You see the person. You see their screaming face. You hear the scream.  You put two and two together to make four.  You see the person scream.

It is a completely normal way to express this idea.

It would be odd to say "I saw a scream".

Answer (score 1):

As JamesK says, this is perfectly reasonable. If you are in a crowded area, it may well be relevant to say that you saw who it was that screamed. To push things a little, you may not actually hear the scream, but still see the act occurring.

To answer the other side of your question, if you want to emphasise the sound side of things, it would be perfectly normal to say "I heard someone scream" - this would indeed be the only correct angle if you had your back to the scene (or whatever) and didn't see the act.